# Grails spring Security add authentication method

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have an application that requires the users to choose between 2 different authentication methods.
One being username/password authentication and the other being username/password/one-time-password.

i have created the additional authentication provider and it works well when overriding the daoAuthenticationProvider provider in my resources.groovy as done in http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1090

however now when i need my authentication method to live side by side with the standard daoAuthenticationProvider i am a bit stuck.

I know i have my custom authentication provider and a custom filter registered in resources.groovy. The question is how do i make a url("redirect /my_auth to the filter") be intercepted by my custom filter?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of registering the filters in resources.groovy, you can do this using filterChain configurations in Config.groovy. Declare all the filters spring security will be using in filterchain.filterNames, including both the standard filters you want, as well as your custom ones:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.filterChain.filterNames = [
   'securityContextPersistenceFilter', 'logoutFilter',
   'authenticationProcessingFilter', 'firstCustomFilter','secondCustomFilter',
   'rememberMeAuthenticationFilter', 'anonymousAuthenticationFilter',
   'exceptionTranslationFilter', 'filterInvocationInterceptor'
]
```

Then map your custom filters to specific URLs - one way to do this using exclusions is as follows:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    '/customUrlOne/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-secondCustomFilter',
    '/customUrlTwo/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-firstCustomFilter',
    '/**':  'JOINED_FILTERS,-firstCustomFilter,-secondCustomFilter'
]
```

**JOINED_FILTERS** is the set of all filters you've declared in the first map. Under "/**", all filters except your custom filters which have been excluded will be active. Similarly, under the custom URLs, all filters, minus the excluded custom filter meant for the other URL will be active. This will ensure that traffic going to *customUrlOne* will be intercepted by *firstCustomFilter*, and traffic going to *customUrlTwo* will be intercepted by *secondCustomFilter*.

Comment: Did not get this to work. Uncommented my filter registration in resources.groovy and added the code as above, Get a complaint that my filter is not found during startup(Makes sense that i need to register it right?).
Even if i register it something wrong happens in the chainmap since it never seems to hit my custom filter

Comment: For now i created an alternate solution where my login form posts a field for the authentication method, I then register one filter as the authenticationProcessingFilter and in there determine what authentication object to create based on the proposed authentication method. 
the authentication objects are wired to my authentication provider as follows
 boolean supports(Class<? extends Object> authenticationClass) {
        CustomAuthentication.isAssignableFrom authenticationClass
    }

However you solution is much more elegant if i can get it to work :)